# swap space being used a little bit

Tags: java, memory, jboss, cpu-usage

I am running an enterprise application running on JBoss on different 20 servers. I have been seeing an issue where after 24 hours of uptime, I have to restart JBoss because the system load is going very high and it is impacting customer user experience.

I have tried to troubleshoot this using VisialVM, JAVA mission control to find out what exactly in the thread is causing the system load to go so high ( around 20 to 50) if kept UP for more than 24 hours.

I want to turn my attention to memory leak now as a probably cause. All the nodes have 6 CPUs and 16GB of RAM.

```
[user@server 2015_12_27_05_07_32_32631]$ top -M
top - 15:55:49 up 19 days, 13:33,  3 users,  load average: 11.19, 9.83, 8.92
Tasks: 280 total,   1 running, 279 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 91.6%us,  3.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 4.5%id,  0.1%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.3%si,     0.0%st
Mem:    15.577G total,   15.275G used,  309.852M free,   53.969M buffers
Swap: 4095.992M total,  200.824M used, 3895.168M free, 6373.957M cached
```

If I do a top -M on all the nodes, I do see the swap space is being used but like 100 ~ 200 MB out of the 4GB assigned. Can I take this as a sign on memory leak ?

What tools can I use to determine the CPU usage going so high if the application is left to stay UP without restarting it.

I am adding a sample of VisualVM.  [image: See attached image]

This is VisualVM output of when the node is experiencing high CPU/load.

[image: This is VisualVM output of when the node is experiencing high CPU/load.]

The below is showing the blocked threads :

[image: blocked threads]

Comment: I'd like to see the output of VisualVM, it should show that your memory increases and cannot decrease after a GC.  Output of the GC would be useful too.  You may have a leak but hard to say just from `top`.

Comment: You could monitor a node's VM for very long (the whole 24 hours) to see whether the heap size is growing.

Comment: @markspace :   Ive added a VisualVM snapshot

Comment: Your heap usage varies between 1G and 4G, with over 7 available.  Based on that, no leak.  Something else is causing the system to exhibit high latency. That graph BTW shows about 2 hours of activity.  Is this before or after the problem occurs?

Comment: @markspace : Right now the node is behaving normally since the application was rebooted less than 24 hours ago. 

As of now its been 12 hours. I am attaching anther image of VisualVM output as to when the issue was occurring.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a memory leak, or at least looks a lot like one.  You'll have to dig through the perm gen to figure out which objects are being retained, then figure out who is hanging on to them.  I'm not an expert, so there might be better ways to go about this.

Comment: Before that though, I notice your thread usage also spikes up.  Can you determine what those threads are doing?  Like are they all blocked on the same part of code?  Something could be consuming threads, and then your memory spikes up when the system tries to allocate even more threads, and that spikes memory usage.

Comment: @markspace : Thanks for the input. Since this happens all so randomly, I might need to put in monitoring scripts and find out whats happening on a thread level.

Comment: @markspace When we view the threads, I see alot of log4j threads taking a lot of time. 
We are logging everthing on DEBUG level and the application servers upto 8 million customers.